# Fill the different colors in the circles and add some text

Tags: color, text, circles

Question: I want to fill different colors in all four circles. Further how can I add some text inside the circles (see the attached figure)

I am looking for this figure [image]

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[bindingoffset=0.2in,left=0.5in,right=0.5in,top=0.5in,bottom=0.5in,footskip=.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage[centertags]{amsmath}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{newlfont}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,intersections}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
        \foreach \x in {0,1,2,3}
        \draw[color=black,very thick] (0,\x) circle [radius=\x+1];
        \draw[color=black] (0.01,0.01) node {\textcolor{black}{\textbf{Natural Numbers}}};
        \draw[color=black] (0.005,1.75) node {\textcolor{black}{\textbf{Whole Numbers}}};
        \draw[color=black] (-0.1,3.95) node {\textcolor{black}{\textbf{Integers}}};
        \draw[color=black] (0.0,6) node {\textcolor{black}{\textbf{Rational Numbers}}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to do it. Keys:

- drop, what's not needed here
- pass data-pairs to loop
- count backwards within the loop
- use styles
- `align=center` is one way to have line breaks via `\\`

[image: result]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%\usepackage[bindingoffset=0.2in,left=0.5in,right=0.5in,top=0.5in,bottom=0.5in,footskip=.25in]{geometry}
%\usepackage[centertags]{amsmath}
%\usepackage{latexsym}
%\usepackage{amsfonts}
%\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{amsthm}
%\usepackage{newlfont}
%\usepackage{enumerate}
%\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{xparse}
%\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,intersections}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        scale=2,
        transform shape,
        txt/.style={align=center,font=\bfseries\sf\tiny},
    ]
        \foreach \x/\clr in {4/yellow,3/teal!40,2/red,1/blue!20}
        \draw[color=black,very thick,fill=\clr] (0,\x) circle [radius=\x];
        
        \node[txt] at (0,7) {Rational Numbers\\p/q form};
        
        \node[txt] at (0,1) {Natural Numbers\\1, 2, 3, \dots};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank for replying but still it has issues like few text are missing in second and third circle

Comment: Right, by intention. I'm sure you can fill in the blanks by copy&adapt ;-)

Comment: It's done. Once again thank you so much.